# NuGet metapackage in a project doesn't allow the project to refer to its contents

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

There are several analyzers whose NuGet packages I almost always include in any project I make.  It's annoying adding them all individually whenever I start a new project, so I have long wanted to make a NuGet package of my own that just says "include these other packages".  I recently did so, and it seems to work fine.  I made the following nuspec file, did a "nuget pack" and then a "nuget push" to a private package server:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Rwv37.Metapackage.Analyzers</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Robert William Vesterman</authors>
    <owners>Robert William Vesterman</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A collection of frequently used analyzers.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019 Robert William Vesterman</copyright>
    <developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="netstandard2.0">
        <dependency id="CSharpGuidelinesAnalyzer" version="3.1.0" />
        <dependency id="IDisposableAnalyzers" version="2.1.2" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" version="2.9.4" />
        <dependency id="StyleCop.Analyzers" version="1.1.118" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I then decided to do the same thing with a bunch of test-related packages that I almost always include in all of my unit test projects:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Rwv37.Metapackage.UnitTesting</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Robert William Vesterman</authors>
    <owners>Robert William Vesterman</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A collection of frequently used unit testing stuff.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019 Robert William Vesterman</copyright>
    <developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="netstandard2.0">
        <dependency id="FluentAssertions" version="5.7.0" />
        <dependency id="FluentAssertions.Analyzers" version="0.11.4" />
        <dependency id="Moq" version="4.12.0" />
        <dependency id="Moq.Analyzers" version="0.0.7" />
        <dependency id="xunit" version="2.4.1" />
        <dependency id="xunit.analyzers" version="0.10.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

That did not work.  When I add this metapackage to a unit testing project, I can see it (and its constituent packages) in VS 2019's Solution Explorer, but I get a bunch of errors saying things like:

> The type or namespace name 'FluentAssertions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I thought maybe I was misunderstanding the "developmentDependency" tag, so I removed that and bumped the version number, but this did not help.

What am I doing wrong? How do I do it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: When you used the package in your project, expand Dependencies/NuGet/Rwv37.Metapackage.UnitTesting. Are the other packages are listed as dependencies?

Comment: zivkan, yes, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It seems like it is due to some Visual Studio caching wackiness or something like that.  As I noted in the original post, after I found that it didn't work, I removed the "developmentDependency" tag and bumped the version number, which did not help.

However, the way that I had upgraded the project to use the new version was via "Update" in VS's NuGet Package Manager.  Just now, I instead tried uninstalling the old version, then installing the new version.  It magically started working.

I tried each way a few more times, and it always was the same: If I "Update" version 1 to version 2, it doesn't work, but if I "Uninstall" version 1 and then "Install" version 2, it works fine.

Just for the sake of completeness, I will also mention that prior to discovering this workaround, I had tried various things like clean/rebuild, unload project/reload project, close VS/open VS, and combinations thereof (like clean/close/open/rebuild), none of which helped.